# How to let an image matches another image's height using RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I wanted to put **`ImageB`** on top of **`ImageA`**. How should I achieve that?

[image]

Note:

- I don't want to fix my height for both images so that I can maintain their aspect ratio.
- The height for **`ImageA`** and **`ImageB`** are different.

  ```
  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="match_parent">

      <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageA"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:scaleType="fitCenter"
      android:src="@drawable/imageA" 
      android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

      <!-- How to let imageB matches imageA's height ? -->
      <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageB"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:src="@drawable/imageB"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
  ```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you can use android:alignTop="@id/imageA" and alignBottom="@id/imageA"

Comment: I agree with  @Phan Văn Linh ans try this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageA"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/imageA" 
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

    <!-- How to match let imageB matches imageA's height ? -->
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageB"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/imageA" // add it
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/imageA" // add it
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" // remove it
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/imageB"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this help